# VSCode: 3 dots popping up and disappearing in editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

I have VSCode installed with

Version: 1.52.0-insider (user setup)

Commit: 0a80aacc7be1ab03ec0f94b8ac1a84949a83f35d

Date: 2020-11-26T07:36:22.965Z

Electron: 11.0.2

Chrome: 87.0.4280.63

Node.js: 12.18.3

V8: 8.7.220.24-electron.0

OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19042

I also installed C/C++ for Visual Studio Code 1.1.2.

Then created some hpp file.

Also when hitting enter on some random line, 3 dots appear on some strange empty lines.

After 2 seconds these dots and lines disappear again.

This makes working in the editor really hard when lines come and go.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Any idea how to disable these popping up dots?

Comment: what does the tooltip of these `...` say? Have a look at CodeLens settings for cpp files. or they are CodeActions

Comment: Isn't that the symbol for folded content? Strange  that no fold markers are visible.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me because of the GitLens extension. I uninstalled it and now the issue is gone. It seems they have open issues for this issue but they are not addressed (as of today)
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/111472
https://github.com/gitkraken/vscode-gitlens/issues/1312